# ValueError: object too deep for desired array (netcdf)

Tags: python, list, netcdf, sift

I am trying to pass `SIFT` features to netcdf file but when I tried to do then it shows me following error(I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and coding in python).

> File "/home/Research/netcdf_helpers.py", line 15, in createNcVar
>       nc_var.assignValue(data) ValueError: object too deep for desired array

I searched various solutions but still finding the correct solution for this.

Current format of my data structure is as follows:

```
[[(file1feature1,file1feature2,file1feature3,file1feature4,file1feature5),(file2feature1,file2feature2,file2feature3,file2feature4,file2feature5)(file3feature1,file3feature2,file3feature3,file3feature4,file3feature5)]]
```

The desired output I am looking to achieve is as follows:

```
[file1feature1,file1feature2,file1feature3,file1feature4,file2feature5,file2feature1,file2feature2,file2feature3,file2feature4.......]
```

I have consumed half of my day for correcting this error but still struggling. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: With respect to the desired output, do you require the list to be sorted and if yes is it just exactly the way its specified above?

Comment: Actually, I need features values from an image, its not essential the list to be sorted.

Comment: The answer below, does it achieve the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

In order to mimic your data structure I used following data:

```
raw_data = [[(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7), (5, 6, 0)]]]  # this is the raw data
```

Following operation achieves the structure you are after:

```
data = () # place holder for your filtered data

for entry in raw_data[0]:  # operation
    data += entry
```

**Output:**

```
print(list(data)) # [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6, 0]
```

Comment: The statement which is extracting SIFT features is as follows,                    temp = (point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave, point.class_id)                                                                                               If I will take 30 SIFT keypoints then for every keypoint the temp will record 5 features point and assigned to temp. After that I am appending a local list. The global list is appending with local list values and for next image the local list will be empty initially.

Comment: The code above should transform the raw output of that operation into the desired output you've declared in your original post.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not actual solution I am looking for. I am not sure about the data[ ][ ] because I am using huge dataset. I want general solution not to be specific with the elements of array. No matter how many elements in array I want at the end [1,2,3,4,5,6,7....]

Comment: https://github.com/jpuigcerver/rnnlib/blob/master/utils/netcdf_helpers.py In this file the line 30 is creating problem for my code. I passed all values this file requires but when I passed feature values to it, I stucked with an error as mentioned above.

Comment: The initial solution has been a generic. The edited version is independed from no. of elements in your row data.

Comment: The data = ()  should be data = [ ], then it works perfectly. Thanks again, your solution worked for asked problem but stucked me with another error as                                                                                                  ValueError: shapes are not aligned

Comment: @Saad glad the solution has been useful. I would appreciate if you could either up-vote the solution or accept it as an answer :)